# Не могу расположить правильно текст

Tags: css, текст, style, index

[image: Текст перемещается только цельным куском, не сказал бы что это блок как таковой. Если менять значение display то он просто пропадает. Новичёк я еще)]

Вот так выглядит сам код в style.css, может тут что не так.

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .tm-main-nav {
        display: flex ;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

    .tm-top-column { 
        position: block; 
        height: 100%;
    }
```

А так все выглядит на основной странице

```
 <nav class="tm-main-nav">
    <ul class="tm-main-nav-ul">
    <li class="tm-nav-item">
    <a href="#ward" class="tm-nav-item-link">О палате</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tm-nav-item">
    <a href="#applicants" class="tm-nav-item-link">Претендентам</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tm-nav-item">
    <a href="#members" class="tm-nav-item-link">Членам палаты</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tm-nav-item">
    <a href="#registry" class="tm-nav-item-link">Реестр</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tm-nav-item">
    <a href="#patrial" class="tm-nav-item-link">Гражданам</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tm-nav-item">
    <a href="#training" class="tm-nav-item-link">Обучение</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tm-nav-item">
    <a href="#contact" class="tm-nav-item-link">Контакты</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Вы написали, что не можете расположить правильно текст. А как это "правильно"? На разрешении экрана больше 992px содержимое центрируется. А как должно быть?

Comment: Простите за формулировку, был не так точен, да и ошибка оказалась не такая уж и сложная. Проблема была в моей невнимательности, не тот блок перебирал. Извините за трату времени.